# Using VBA arrays to synchronize three sheets into one

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, alignment

I managed to sync selected data from three sheets into a fourth sheet. But the data doesn't align properly after empty cells beginning with the 14th row.

Now I'm trying to use **arrays** to align my data better. I have 3 sheets with columns `Area`, `Zone`, `Employee` and 6 numeric columns for each employee.

The data in `Area`, `Zone` & `Employee` is repeating itself in multiple rows so I need to add the numbers for every employee to have the `Employee Name` displayed only once with added data in other 6 columns.

I don't really have problem with filtering the names and adding data, but I'm not sure how to do it **using arrays**.

Or if anyone could help me find a mistake in my code that's causing the data to not align properly, I would also appreciate it.  Below is my code so far, hopefully it would help.

```
Private Sub cmd_button1_Click()
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet
    Set WS1 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Distribution")
    Set ws3 = Sheets("Sheet3")
    Set ws4 = Sheets("Sheet4")
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim R As Long, LR As Long, n As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Getting the row number of last cell
    LastRow = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Deleting any previous data from destination sheet
    ws2.Range("A2:AX10000").ClearContents

    For i = 1 To 10
        'If value in V column of the row is "" then copy the row to destination sheet
        If WS1.Cells(i, "V").Value = "" Then
            WS1.Range("E:E").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A1")
            WS1.Range("F:F").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("B1")
            WS1.Range("G:G").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("C1")
            WS1.Range("A:A").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("E1")
            WS1.Range("O:O").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("F1")
            WS1.Range("P:P").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("G1")
            WS1.Range("R:R").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("H1")
            WS1.Range("S:S").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("I1")
            WS1.Range("Q:Q").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("J1")
            WS1.Range("T:T").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("K1")
            ws3.Range("E:E").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("L1")
            ws3.Range("F:F").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("M1")
            ws3.Range("G:G").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("N1")
            ws3.Range("A:A").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("O1")
            ws3.Range("S:S").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("P1")
            ws3.Range("T:T").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("Q1")
            ws3.Range("V:V").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("R1")
            ws3.Range("W:W").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("S1")
            ws3.Range("X:X").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("T1")
            ws4.Range("F:F").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("U1")
            ws4.Range("G:G").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("V1")
            ws4.Range("H:H").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("W1")
            ws4.Range("A:A").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("X1")
            ws4.Range("L:L").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("Y1")
            ws4.Range("M:M").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("Z1")
            ws4.Range("N:N").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("AA1")
            ws4.Range("O:O").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("AB1")
            ws4.Range("P:P").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("AC1")
            ws4.Range("Q:Q").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("AD1")
        End If
    Next i
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A2:AX" & LR).Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending
    For R = 2 To LR
        'Count the number of duplicates for third row
        n = Application.CountIf(Columns(3), Cells(R, 3).Value)

        'Sum up the values for every duplicate
        Range("F" & R).Value = Evaluate("=Sum(F" & R & ":F" & R + n - 1 & ")")
        Range("G" & R).Value = Evaluate("=Sum(G" & R & ":G" & R + n - 1 & ")")
        Range("H" & R).Value = Evaluate("=Sum(H" & R & ":H" & R + n - 1 & ")")
        Range("I" & R).Value = Evaluate("=Sum(I" & R & ":I" & R + n - 1 & ")")
        Range("J" & R).Value = Evaluate("=Sum(J" & R & ":J" & R + n - 1 & ")")
        Range("K" & R).Value = Evaluate("=Sum(K" & R & ":K" & R + n - 1 & ")")
        Range("E" & R).Value = Evaluate("=Count(E" & R & ":E" & R + n - 1 & ")")
        'Go to next value in third column
        R = R + n - 1
    Next R

    On Error Resume Next
    'Remove all duplicates
    ws2.Range("$A$1:$K$7979").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=3, Header:=xlYes
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Fill out the table with values
    Columns("A:K").AutoFit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

The code above is for synchronizing the sheets with Distribution and filter the data from `Sheet2`, and I have 2 more buttons made to filter the other 2 sheets.

The code below is my attempt to align the data but it's not working correctly.

```
Sub LineEmUp()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, LR As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    LR = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Columns("A:K").Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), _
        Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
    Columns("L:T").Sort Key1:=Range("L2"), _
        Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
    Columns("U:AD").Sort Key1:=Range("U2"), _
        Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

    i = 2

    Do
        If Cells(i, "C") > Cells(i, "N") And Cells(i, "C") > "" Then
            Cells(i, "A").Resize(1, 10).Insert xlShiftDown
        ElseIf Cells(i, "N") > Cells(i, "W") And Cells(i, "N") > "" Then
            Cells(i, "L").Resize(1, 10).Insert xlShiftDown
        ElseIf Cells(i, "W") > Cells(i, "C") And Cells(i, "W") > "" Then
            Cells(i, "U").Resize(1, 10).Insert xlShiftDown
        ElseIf Cells(i, "C") < Cells(i, "N") And Cells(i, "C") > "" Then
            Cells(i, "L").Resize(1, 10).Insert xlShiftDown
        ElseIf Cells(i, "N") < Cells(i, "W") And Cells(i, "N") > "" Then
            Cells(i, "U").Resize(1, 10).Insert xlShiftDown
        ElseIf Cells(i, "W") < Cells(i, "C") And Cells(i, "W") > "" Then
            Cells(i, "A").Resize(1, 10).Insert xlShiftDown
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop Until Cells(i, "C") = "" And Cells(i, "W") = ""

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Hope I explained it properly. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [so]!  Have you tried Excel's built-in functionality for this?  Examples: [HOW TO: Consolidate Multiple Worksheets to a Single Sheet in Excel (Microsoft.com)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214270/how-to-consolidate-multiple-worksheets-to-a-single-sheet-in-excel) and [Consolidate data in multiple worksheets (Office.com)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/consolidate-data-in-multiple-worksheets-007ce8f4-2fae-4fea-9ee5-a0b2c9e36d9b)

Comment: I have to use vba for this.

Comment: Homework?  (It's fine if it is; just easier to help if I understand.)

Comment: No, work stuff and my boss insists that I use vba.

Comment: Ha, bosses are funny.  You could record a macro using the built-in functionality...  that's VBA.  :-)   ...but I'll take a look.

Comment: I tidied up your question a bit so it's easier to understand... now to try to figure this out, it's a lot of code....

Comment: can you show a small set of data that demonstrates this lack of alignment versus what you expect please?

Comment: The first step is to organize so it's more clear what's going on...  I'm going to start an (incomplete) answer to show a cleaner way to do the copies....  but there's a good chance @QHarr will beat me to the punch!

Comment: @ashleedawg I am going to stroll along the sunny beach (literally) for a moment. <smug grin>

Comment: @QHarr -  Literally? You definitely *are* on the other side of the planet, eh?  Coding at the beach, that's much better than my surroundings, lol.

Comment: Added a picture of my table to the question.

Comment: @EnnaSmile - so the picture is the result, and the yellow section is the problem, correct?  Also, did you look at the partial answer below?  -- Is there a reason for copying the ranges out of order? (or could that be part of the problem?)

Comment: Yellow part is yellow in the original sheet, so it stayed that way here, sorry for misunderstandings. The problem is that after 14th row the names aren't aligned properly sometimes and then after 24th row the data is missing all together and is shifted to the end of the table.

Comment: @EnnaSmile - **try `'`commenting out the `removeDuplicates` line and run it again**, that could have something to do with the problem, since it shifts cells around.  **Also**, why the `On Error Resume Next`?  What error was happening before?  (Generally when something causes an error, *"hiding the error & pretending it didn't happen"* is not the right way to deal with it!)

Comment: @QHarr - no need to restrain yourself if you know what the issue is -- I'm kind stuck on cleaning up the repetitive code; it's like an OCD thing.  :)

Comment: Without removeDuplicates I have lots of repeated data and when I tried to align it, the excel is not responding.

Comment: totally understand OCD! Enjoy. Does look like there are extra rows potentially in the middle (sheet 2?)

Comment: I see a **number of culprits**...  Updating my answer below.

Comment: @QHarr - in the middle, um, where?  There's a *lot* going on here.

Comment: I'm not clear on the `LineEmUp` procedure (above)... is this sorting different sections separately?  That will absolutely cause the data to not line up, am I mistaken?  Also I guess you're request to "use arrays" hasn't been addressed yet but I'm not sure what you want to use them *for*?

Comment: I thought that if I would use arrays the code would be shorter and easier to figure out. I assumed that my code is lacking in that synchronizing part and that using arrays would clear that mess up. I'm new at VBA and I was doing my best to align that data, sorry for it being messy..

Comment: @EnnaSmile - try that chat room again https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166673/discussion-on-answer-by-ashleedawg-using-vba-arrays-to-synchronize-three-sheets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Organization (without unnecessary repetition) is always important in coding, and especially key when troubleshooting.  For example, your **29 copy-paste statements** can be tidied up considerably - which shows some inconsistencies.

...I sorted them by source worksheet and then by source column, and grouped them together, also pasting into columns instead of single cells.

---

**Edit:**

There's a number of "weird things" going on here that require some explanation so I know whether they're designed this way intentionally.

**See my "`'<<<<<<`" notes below (There are some specific questions, starting with *what happens if you don't disable screen updating, and don't ignore the errors with `On Error Resume Next`...?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmd_button1_Click()
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet
    Set WS1 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Distribution")
    Set ws3 = Sheets("Sheet3")
    Set ws4 = Sheets("Sheet4")
    'Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim R As Long, LR As Long, n As Long, i As Integer

    ' <<<<< always ALLOW screen updating during troubleshooting, until your code
    ' <<<<< is functioning perfectly: It may give a clue to the problem.
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Getting the row number of last cell  '<<<<< variable [LastRow] is not being used.
    'LastRow = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Deleting any previous data from destination sheet
    'ws2.Range("A2:AX10000").ClearContents
    ws2.UsedRange.ClearContents ' <<<<<< instead of specifying a range, just clear what's used

    For i = 1 To 10
        'If value in V column of the row is "" then copy the row to destination sheet
        If WS1.Cells(i, "V").Value = "" Then
            WS1.Range("A:A").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("E:E")  '<<< there's no pattern to what's being copied,
            WS1.Range("E:G").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A:C")  '<<< (and in a strange criss-cross),
            WS1.Range("O:S").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("F:I")  '<<< are you sure nothing's being missed?
            WS1.Range("T:T").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("K:K")

            ws3.Range("A:A").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("O:O")
            ws3.Range("E:G").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("L:N")
            ws3.Range("S:T").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("P:Q")
            ws3.Range("V:X").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("R:T")

            ws4.Range("A:A").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("X1")
            ws4.Range("F:H").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("U:W")
            ws4.Range("L:Q").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("Y:AD")
        End If
    Next i
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A2:AX" & LR).Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending '<<<<< this could be a problem??
    For R = 2 To LR
        'Count the number of duplicates for third row
        n = Application.CountIf(Columns(3), Cells(R, 3).Value)

        'Sum up the values for every duplicate
        Range("F" & R).Value = Evaluate("=Sum(F" & R & ":F" & R + n - 1 & ")")  '<<<<<< this is a strange way to do this...,
        Range("G" & R).Value = Evaluate("=Sum(G" & R & ":G" & R + n - 1 & ")")  '<<<<<< can you explain the purpose of these lines?
        Range("H" & R).Value = Evaluate("=Sum(H" & R & ":H" & R + n - 1 & ")")  '<<<<<< why not just add the cells normally instead like this?
        Range("I" & R).Value = Evaluate("=Sum(I" & R & ":I" & R + n - 1 & ")")
        Range("J" & R).Value = Evaluate("=Sum(J" & R & ":J" & R + n - 1 & ")")
        Range("K" & R).Value = Evaluate("=Sum(K" & R & ":K" & R + n - 1 & ")")
        Range("E" & R).Value = Evaluate("=Count(E" & R & ":E" & R + n - 1 & ")")
        'Go to next value in third column
        R = R + n - 1 '<<<<<  WOAH!  don't change the value of R when it's being used inside a loop!!!
    Next R

    'On Error Resume Next   '<<<<< Errors mean something - Don't ignore them! (especially during troubleshooting)
    'Remove all duplicates
    ws2.Range("$A$1:$K$7979").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=3, Header:=xlYes '<<< this shifts cells around, might be a problem
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Fill out the table with values
    Columns("A:K").AutoFit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166673/discussion-on-answer-by-ashleedawg-using-vba-arrays-to-synchronize-three-sheets).